# How to reset the value of a C string pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to use the same pointer twice, like this:

```
void* pointer = (char*) malloc(15);
pointer = "Patricia";
printf("%s", pointer);
pointer = "John";
printf("%s", pointer);
```

but the output I'm receiving is this:

```
Patricia
Johnicia
```

Here is the full code (the client script is a python script so I don't find it appropriate to post here)(the John and Patricia are examples of usernames the client might enter):

```
#define MAXCLIENTS 256
#define MAXMSG 269

void forward(int clientslist[MAXCLIENTS], char* msg) {
    int x;
    for (x=0; x < MAXCLIENTS;  x++){
        send(clientslist[x], msg, MAXMSG, 0);
    }
    return;
}

int main(){

    #define PORT 5943

    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int clients[MAXCLIENTS];
    int clientcounter = 0;

    fd_set socketlist, readlist;
    FD_ZERO(&socketlist);
    FD_SET(s, &socketlist);

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(s, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));
    listen(s, MAXCLIENTS);
    int clientsocket;
    int i;
    void* msg = (char *) malloc(MAXMSG);
    void* usr = (char*) malloc(10);


    while (1){
        readlist = socketlist;
        select(FD_SETSIZE, &readlist, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        for (i=0; i<FD_SETSIZE; i++){
            if(FD_ISSET(i, &readlist)){
                if (i == s){
                    clientsocket = accept(s, NULL, NULL);
                    FD_SET(clientsocket, &socketlist);
                    clients[clientcounter] = clientsocket;
                    clientcounter++;
                    recv(clientsocket, usr, 10, 0);
                    printf("Connection received from %s\n", usr);

                } else {
                    recv(i, msg, MAXMSG, 0);
                    forward(clients, msg);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I fix this??
Thanks

Comment: Just set pointer to "John\n" if I am not mistaken. C looks for a string terminator. So if you end "John" with a terminator it will print "John". Not sure about the \n. Might be something else though

Comment: Why do you call `malloc` only to immediate throw away the returned value?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/5SaM7a - also be aware that you are leaking memory with the `malloc`, as you change the pointer right afterward

Comment: @Sheradil "strings" in C are null-terminated, which is `\0`, not `\n`. And string literals are always null-terminated

Comment: I am calling the malloc function since this is a small snippet of code from a much larger program

Comment: Please post a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.  The posted output does not seem like it would go with the posted code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recv` returns the number of bytes read, and you just need to add a null terminator.  eg:

```
ssize_t rc;
rc = recv(clientsocket, usr, 9, 0);
if( rc >= 0 )
    usr[rc] = '\0';
```

Note that I've reduced the length argument in the call to recv to ensure that there is space for the terminator.  If you expect to receive messages of length 10, you would want to allocate at least 11 bytes for usr.  However, with buffers that small, it would probably be cleaner to use an array and do:

```
char usr[11];
ssize_t rc;
rc = recv(clientsocket, usr, sizeof usr - 1, 0);
if( rc >= 0 )
    usr[rc] = '\0';
```